# How to change existing "Build Your Own"(Aura) template to Build Your Own(LWR)?

Tags: community, experience-cloud, lwr

We are currently enhancing our Experience Cloud site with the latest LWR template to access new Features and improving site performance.

We already have an existing site which uses "Build Your Own(Aura)" template and we have a URL configured for this. We want to change the template to "Build Your Own(LWR)" so that we can keep the same site URL and necessary components there but when I try to change the template, it does not display "Build Your Own(LWR)" template in the list?

Can someone suggest how to upgrade your existing site to LWR by changing the template?

The only option I tried as to rename existing site and then create new LWR site and all components there but I am worried about how it would work during deployment to other environments?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_template_change.htm&type=5 does this answer your question?

Comment: Before switching template, remember to check the [limitation of Build Your Own(LWR)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/template_limitations.htm) and review your custom LWC to be sure [they are compatibile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_comp_limitations.htm) with this template.

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi, Seems I have to create a new site based on information in article :(

Comment: @RubenDG Yes I did check the limitation. but template switch option is not available.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil, I am posting my comment as answer. it will help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your template affects the Experience Cloud site navigation, branding, and customizations.

> Apart from the Help Center template, we don’t recommend changing from
> one Experience Builder template to another. So for example, avoid
> changing from a Customer Service template to a Partner Central
> template. Although the functionality is available for these templates,
> we recommend that you start afresh with a new Experience Cloud site
> instead. If you do change from one Experience Builder template to
> another and lose your customizations, Salesforce Customer Support is
> unable to assist you.
>
> When you change a template, always select a template with the same
> underlying programming model. For example, change from one Lightning
> Web Runtime (LWR) template to another LWR template, or from an Aura
> template to another Aura template.

Refer the [Considerations for Changing Your Template](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_template_considerations.htm&type=5)